# Border radius not working on certain android telephones

Tags: android, html, css, border

I have a simple section in which I have added a border-radius, unfortunately, I have tested on android phones eg xiaomi redmi note 4 , xiaomi redmi 3 pro, motorola g6, border radius is not working

Here is HTML

```
<div class="video-conatiner_datavideo">
                    <video class="videoplayer-datavideo" id="videoplayer"
                        playsinline autoplay muted>
                        <source src="videos/welcome_middle_generyczny_bot.mp4"
                            type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                </div>
```

here is css

```
.videoplayer-datavideo {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-top-left-radius: 300px;
    border-top-right-radius: 300px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 300px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 300px;
}
```

I have tried to change to this

```
.videoplayer-datavideo {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 300px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 300px;
    -moz-border-radius: 300px;
    -ms-border-radius: 300px;
    -o-border-radius: 300px;
}
```

Still not working

But when I try on iPhones, and other android devices everything is fine

Here is live demo : [Live demo](https://videomill-bot.audiencevideo.com/ideabank-bot/)

What do I need to do to solve this problem?

Comment: "border radius is not working" - not at all or not how you expect? What browsers do you have the problem on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.videoplayer-datavideo {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-conatiner_datavideo">
  <video class="videoplayer-datavideo" id="videoplayer" playsinline autoplay muted>
      <source src="videos/welcome_middle_generyczny_bot.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```